# Prove that if f is continuous in a, then $\forall \epsilon > 0, ∃ \delta >0: $ $|x-a|< \delta $ & $|y-a| < \delta $ $ then |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon $

Tags: calculus

> Prove that if f is continuous in a, then $\forall \epsilon > 0,  \exists \delta >0: $ when  $|x-a|< \delta $ & $|y-a| < \delta $ then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon $

For the definition of continuity in a I have:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0,  \exists \delta: |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon if |x-a| < \delta$$

My idea was to take any $\delta > 0 $ and then take a = y, but I don't know if that's a correct way to do it.

Comment: That is not correct. You can’t *pick* $y$. Try to use triangle inequality $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)-f(y)|.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta  >0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

$\forall x,y$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$.

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|[f(x)-f(a)]+[f(a)-f(y)]|\le|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)=f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

---

Note: You cannot take $a=y$ as $a$ is fixed.

Comment: So I can assume that $|f(a)-f(y)| < ϵ/2 $

Comment: We cannot assume $|f(a)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. We can only assume $|y-a|<\delta$. Things like  $|f(a)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ can only be a consequence of the assumption.